# What are the continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, problem-solving

Suppose $X = [0,1]$ is a topological space with $\tau = \{\{\},[0,1/2],(1/2,1], X\}$. I want to find (classify) all of the continuous functions from $X$ to the reals.

I have tried to find the preimage of the function on any open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that they are elements of $\tau$ (such that the function takes the range as one of the elements in $\tau$) but it seems to be useless and I have no idea what I should do next. Would anyone please give me some hints on this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The continuous functions are exactly the functions which are constant on the sets $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $(\frac{1}{2},1]$. It is easy to check that such functions are indeed continuous. Now we'll show why these are all the continuous functions.

Suppose $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and we'll show that this function is constant on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$. Let $x,y\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$, and write $f(x)=c$. The set $\{c\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, and by continuity $f^{-1}(c)$ has to be closed in $X$. It is easy to check that the closed sets of $X$ are exactly the elements of $\tau$. Since $x\in f^{-1}(c)$ we know that this inverse image can't be $\emptyset$ or $(\frac{1}{2},1]$. Hence it is either $X$ or $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, and in either case $y\in f^{-1}(c)$, i.e $f(y)=c$. Similarly we can show that $f$ is constant on $(\frac{1}{2},1]$.

Comment: The sentence "the closed sets of $X$ are exactly the elements of $\tau$" might be a little bit confusing without elaboration: the reason is that this topology is closed under complements, which is an unusual thing.

Comment: You are right, this is not something which usually happens. But it is easy to check, there are just $4$ sets in this topology.

Comment: Yeah this is better, as it makes it more apparent that this statement is specific to this problem. +1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just curious, is it possible to answer this question using the open sets' definition of continuous function?

Comment: @Ming Well, we could compute $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{c\})$ (which is an open set in $X$) instead of $f^{-1}(c)$ and get the same result.

Comment: @Mark ahh! Thanks!!